# SQL How to return record ID's not included in table 2 from table 1 based off of user ID in table 2

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, one has course name and course ID. The second table has the ID of the students and the course ID they have taken. I need to find all the class ID’s of the classes a student hasn’t taken. For example, in table 2 student 03 has taken classes 01 and 02 but not 03 and 04 from table one. The course ID’s 03 and 04 from table one are what I need to return (all the classes student 03 hasn't taken). I've tried numerous queries and the last one I tried is:

```
SELECT table1.* FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON
    table1.course_ID = table2.course_ID
WHERE
    table2.course_ID IS NULL
AND 
    table2.user_ID != 3
```

Appreciate your help!

table 1

| course_ID | courseName |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | math |
| 02 | English |
| 03 | art |
| 04 | music |

table 2

| cert_Id | course_ID | user_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 01 | 03 |
| 02 | 02 | 03 |

Comment: *`table2.user_ID != 3`* must be a part of ON clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your current requirement below query will work

```
    SELECT * FROM table1 t1 
    WHERE course_ID 
    NOT IN (SELECT course_ID FROM table2 WHERE user_ID =3)
```

If you have more records in table2 and if you need to populate more than one student's details then you have to use other logic

If you want to modify your query then use as below

```
    SELECT table1.* FROM table1 
         LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.course_ID = table2.course_ID 
         AND table2.user_ID = 3 
    WHERE table2.course_ID IS NULL
```

Comment: This worked perfect, it's really simple, I think I was making it too difficult. Thank you, thank you, thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select t1.* from table1 as t1
left join table2 as t2 on t2.course_ID = t1.course_ID and t2.user_ID = 3 
where t2.user_ID is null;
```

For more readable query, you can use [`EXCEPT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/except.html) if available:

```sql
select * from table1
except
select t1.* from table1 as t1
inner join table2 as t2 on t2.course_ID = t1.course_ID and t2.user_ID = 3;
```